# How to preserve leading zeros when converting to a decimal in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, decimal

I am running the below query in oracle.

```
WITH
ta AS (
     SELECT account_coid
        ,txn_id
        ,cbdev.cbzdt(effective_date) AS effective_date
        ,cbdev.cbchr(utl_raw.substr(txn_data, 113, 20)) AS CESG_amt
     FROM bs_transaction
     WHERE sub_type = 127469880)
SELECT
cast(ta.CESG_amt as DECIMAL (20,2)) AS cesg_amt
from ta 
inner join ....
```

Here, i m getting the result (`cesg_amt`) as `-156.57`.  But i need the result as `-0000000000156.57`.
I need the leading zeros with `-` retained (leading 0's and also the two digits after the decimal).

I have tried as `to_char(ta.CESG_amt, '0000000000000.00') AS cesg_amt` in the query but of no use.

Can you please help me what needs to be done in the DECIMAL field to get the result as below.

Comment: `to_char()` should be doing what you want.

Comment: In what way is `to_char()` of no use? What happens when you use it? Also, it is most common to use the NUMBER datatype in Oracle, rather than DECIMAL.

Comment: @Boneist when i use to_char() in this case, i m getting the value as 0.00 surprisingly.  I m using this query in a script with calls to the oracle db. Any idea about what might be wrong.

Comment: `in a script with calls to the oracle db` what kind of script? A unix script? A SQL*Plus script? Something else? What happens if you run the query directly against the database (e.g. in SQL*PLus/Toad/SQL Developer/etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use such a formatting :

```
select to_char(-156.57,'fm0000000000000D00','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')
       as Result
  from dual;

RESULT
-----------------
-0000000000156.57
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Basically i m using this query in a shell script. But when i use to_char () with whatever formatting, i m getting the result as 0.00 surprisingly.  Any idea.

Comment: @SatyanveshD welcome. Maybe you assign the result to a variable with insufficient length, in your script ... Maybe of type number( x, 2) ...

Comment: thank you so much.  yeah your logic was correct. In the script, the result was getting truncated due to assigning it to different variable. I have gone through the entire script and removed that now. Its working fine with to_char function now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select to_char(-156.57,'000000000.00')
  from dual;
```