# ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SUBSTR'

Tags: sql, oracle, substr, ora-06553

I'm running the below query in oracle and i m facing the error **ORA-06553**.

```
select cast(cbdev.cbchr(utl_raw.substr(4500, 5, 26)) AS DECIMAL (14, 2)) as grant_held 
  from bs_transaction 
 where account_coid = 'TS 0014 T8324J3L2V' 
   and txn_id = 21;
```

Not sure why substr is throwing error when the syntax seem to be correct.
Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: First parameter to [`substr`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679) should be a string, not a number (`4500`), I guess.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_raw.htm#BABIFIJB

Comment: @Satyanvesh D: So you have `bs_transaction` table; which *field* of type `raw` do you want to process? What is the meaning of `4500` in your query? Could you, please, put the initial problem in plain English? Like "I have `bs_transaction` with a field `data` from which I want to extract ... "

Comment: As [the documentation for  UTL_RAW states](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_raw.htm#ARPLS71416) the first argument in `utl_raw.substr()` must be a RAW datatype. You're passing a number. Given that you are querying a table presumably you ought to be passing a column name there.

Comment: In [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53411625/266304) you seem to be passing `txn_data` into that function successfully - should you just still be using that? Why did you change it to 4500 and what is that supposed to represent?

Comment: Clearly you need to expand your question with more details about you program and the business rules you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select cast(cbdev.cbchr(utl_raw.substr('4500', 5, 26)) AS DECIMAL (14, 2)) as grant_held 
  from bs_transaction 
 where account_coid = 'TS 0014 T8324J3L2V' 
   and txn_id = 21;
```

Comment: I doubt that OP wants **26** characters starting from **5** being extracted from just `'4500'`. Moreover, `utl_raw.substr` wants *raw* first argument. Probably it should be `...utl_raw.substr(Some_Raw_Field, 5, 26)...`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko  exactly. I want some raw field in that place. what is it wrong there. How to pass it correctly. Any idea please.

Comment: @Joe Love . i have tried that but still i m facing the same error.

Comment: @SatyanveshD - where is this raw supposed to come from? is it a column on the table you're querying?

Comment: @APC - no, its not from the table. This particular raw should be coming as an user input which is where i m not able to get it correctly.